# mongoose create DB not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Neither `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/sync-db');` nor `mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/sync-db');` is creating the `sync-db` on local host.

Though both connection callbacks are successfully connected. But when I tried to check both **robo-mongo** and **mongod client** console using the command `show dbs`, the `sync-db` is neither to be seen on **robo-mongo** nor on **mongod client**

**WTF?**

Comment: By default, if you have no collection in the database, the database does not exist. The same for collections, if no document is in, the collection does not exist. So, yes it is working, just not visible in cli for now until a document is added in a collection.

Comment: Ooooh I see. Let me just try it. :) @Odonno

Comment: @Odonno You're right thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since no one is answering this question, I will post my own answer based on what [@Odonno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6621332/odonno) said on the comment, which is correct.

The codes above use to create database is not wrong, in the background the database has already been created, but for some reason (I hope someone will explain this) you wont see it until you added some data to it.